# configure multiple servers on spring configuration client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, server, cluster-computing

I got a distributed system and like to use spring configuration server.

Addressing a single server instance is no problem at all. What I like to do is building up a cluster of configuration servers, similar like it is done with Eureka server.

The problem I am facing is I don't know how to configure it on the client.

First attempt was:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://server.A.com:8888,http://server.B.com:8888,http://server.C.com:8888
```

What I received was a "invalid URL" exception.

Comment: Why not use eureka? Register the config servers with Eureka and use that to pick an instance.

Comment: Isn't that too late? I read the first thing a spring boot application does is to search for a config-server. The spring.cloud.counfig.uri has to be set in bootstrap for this reason.

Comment: Then read a bit [more](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap). There is a special section in the reference guide for that.

Comment: Superb! Thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I would mark it as the right one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i have more than one Spring Cloud Config Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604163/can-i-have-more-than-one-spring-cloud-config-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Config can simply use the discovery mechanism to detect the config server(s) and use that to get the configuration. This behavior is by default switched off.

To enable add the `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true` in the `bootstrap.yml` file and put the config service configuration and eureka configuration in there.

For more information read the [Discovery first bootstrap](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap) section in the Spring Cloud Config reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Finchley release supports specifying multiple URL's for config server in the Configuration First bootstrap setup.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR4/single/spring-cloud.html#_specifying_multiple_urls_for_the_config_server

> To ensure high availability when you have multiple instances of Config Server deployed and expect one or more instances to be unavailable from time to time, you can either specify multiple URLs (as a comma-separated list under the spring.cloud.config.uri property)